# run ssh commands on vxworks with ansible

Tags: ansible

I have some old equipment that I manage and it is running VXWorks.  I am able to ssh into it and run commands, but the commands and/or the prompts are not standard.  I would like to use ansible to automate some of the tasks that I do.  I am not sure what module to use for this.

1. Is there a way to just ssh into a box and start running commands with Ansible for non Linux boxes?
2. Is there a way to download files via scp/sftp with Ansible for non Linux boxes?
3. How can I get the raw output.  The commands I run are generally show commands and I need to see the output of the commands.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to just ssh into a box and start running commands with Ansible for non Linux boxes?

That's what Ansible's `raw` module is for: it's a minimal wrapper for `ssh <somehost> <somecommand>`.

> Is there a way to download files via scp/sftp with Ansible for non Linux boxes?

If the remote system supports `scp` or `sftp`, your Ansible playbooks can just run the appropriate `scp`/`sftp` command on your local system. E.g.,

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: copy a file from the remote system
      command: scp myserver:somefile.txt .
```

> How can I get the raw output. The commands I run are generally show commands and I need to see the output of the commands.

When you run a command in a playbook, you can `register` the result, and for `raw` tasks that registered variable will have `stdout` and `stderr` attributes containing the output from the command.  For example:

```
- hosts: myserver
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: demonstrate the raw module
      raw: date
      register: date

    - debug:
        var: date.stdout
```

The output from that playbook will include:

```
TASK [demonstrate the raw module] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [myserver]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myserver] => {
    "date.stdout": "Fri Dec 18 09:09:34 PM EST 2020\r\n"
}
```

The `gather_facts: false` part is critical, because that prevents Ansible from trying to implicitly run the `setup` module on your target host.